# Can't use HTTPS sites with VFP9/MSXML2.XMLHTTP

Tags: visual-foxpro, msxml, serverxmlhttp

I'm fixing some really old software.

It's written in VFP9 and uses MSXML2.XMLHTTP for accessing web APIs.

It works fine using unsecured (HTTP) sites, but not HTTPS sites, which is required.

My assumption is that MSXML2.XMLHTTP is using only obsolete SSL or something. I tried MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0 and same thing.

Are there updated XMLHTTP COM objects available that can talk to modern HTTPS servers?

Or is there a better option for VFP9 consuming HTTPS?

---

I just tried using West Wind's wwclient.zip, and it was updated this year, and that doesn't do modern HTTPS either. So that's out. HTTP works fine. HTTPS gets nothing.

---

Also, what I'm testing on is Windows XP. That might be an issue.

---

**Update**: It's definitely WinXP because the same code works on newer Windows. So the question is really how to update MSXML2.XMLHTTP on WinXP to work with modern HTTPS.

Comment: There seems to be a solution for a similar `VB6`  classic issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942787/vb6-http-post-request-on-windows-xp

Comment: What is modern HTTPS? I use MSXML2.XMLHTTP against HTTPS successfully. If you think it would make you feel you better thinking you are using modern, you could create activex say in C#.

Comment: Modern HTTPS uses TLS 1.2. Some sites, such as Google, still serve up SSL for old clients, but most don't.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with old versions of Windows and MSXML2.XMLHTTP, thanks to Rick Strahl for the tip:

https://west-wind.com/wconnect/weblog/ShowEntry.blog?id=937&id=937